# scrapy: Remove elements from an xpath selector

Tags: xpath, lxml, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl a site with some odd formatting conventions.  The basic idea is that I want all the text and subelements of a certain div, EXCEPT a few at the beginning, and a few at the end.

Here's the gist.

```
<div id="easy-id">
  <stuff I don't want>
  text I don't want
  <div id="another-easy-id" more stuff I don't want>

  text I want
  <stuff I want>
  ...
  <more stuff I want>
  text I want
  ...

  <div id="one-more-easy-id" more stuff I *don't* want>
  <more stuff I *don't* want>
```

NB: The indenting implies closing tags, so everything here is a child of the first div -- the one with id="easy-id"

Because text and nodes are mixed, I haven't been able to figure out a simple xpath selector to grab the stuff I want.  At this point, I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve the result from xpath as an lxml.etree.elementTree, and then hack at it using the .remove() method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use lxml for parsing , but at the same time Xpath can work , if you tell us what actually you want to grab from this ..

Comment: check out the example -- I've labeled everything as "stuff I want" or "stuff I don't want"

Comment: Does your indenting imply `</div>`, `</stuff>` and `</more>` or is the markup similar to what is here? meaning that the final `<more>` is nested six levels deep?

Comment: it would be good if you paste proper html rather then example , because in your scenario there can not be a generic xpath but exact.

Comment: @stav - The indenting implies closing tags.  Everything here is a child of the first <div id="easy-id">

Comment: @akter - I deliberately avoided full HTML, because the format of these pages isn't very consistent. I don't want people to latch onto features that are just part of an example. I've given ids and tag types for the nodes that follow a reliable format.  If there's an xpath-only solution for this problem, you should have everything you need to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want everything from the div with ID another-easy-id up to but not including the one-more-easy-id div.

Stack overflow has not preserved the indenting, so I do not know where the end of the first div element is, but I'm going to guess it ends before the text.

In that case you might want
    //div[@id = 'another-easy-id']/following:node()
    [not(preceding::div[@id = 'one-more-easy-id']) and not(@id = 'one-more-easy-id')]

If this is XHTML you'll need to bind some prefix, h, say, to the XHTML namespace and use h:div in both places.

EDIT:  Here's the syntax I went with in the end.  (See comments for the reasons.)

```
//div[@id='easy-id']/div[@id='one-more-easy-id']/preceding-sibling::node()[preceding-sibling::div[@id='another-easy-id']]
```

Comment: Awesome.  The node() command is what I was looking for -- something to retrieve both text and element nodes.  A couple small fixes: First, I think you're missing a colon between "following" and "node()".  Second, the way you've written the "following" and "preceding" syntax, it doesn't rule out text nodes that are children of "one-more-easy-id"

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, you're right, sorry. Glad you got there in the end!